# IntelliJ Code coverage Java 8 - requires ASM 5

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

Can anyone help me with this error message I'm getting from IntellIJ?

(I'm using Java 8 - the error is only occurring on a very small percentage of the classes)

[2014.05.06 10:14:39] (Coverage): Error during class instrumentation: xxx.yyyy: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INVOKESPECIAL/STATIC on interfaces require ASM 5

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you Google for that exception message, you will find that there are a small number of  hits in a variety of code analysis tools.  It seems to be a tool-chain compatibility issue.  Java 8 code breaks various third party tools that use older versions of the ASM library.

You need to report this to the developer for the tool or plugin that is having problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have been testing a patch from intellij which fixes the problem.

It will be released publicly in 13.1.3 EAP.

Comment: did you solve this issue? Still seeing this in 13.1.4

Comment: Yes - but they sent me a private patch and I'm still on 13.1.2.  I would contact them about this if it's not working for you.